# Wave-vs.net Pair Programming for Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio, pair-programming, collaborative

Is there a plugin for Visual Studio C++ 2008/2010 express edition just like wave-vs.net live pair programming program?  Or do I have to download and install the full version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Now we have enabled wave-vs.net to support Pair Programming on Visual C++ Project Items.

This new feature has been enabled for Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010.

You can download updated wave-vs.net Plugin from http://www.wave-vs.net

Kind Regards

wave-vs.net Development Team

Comment: Website currently offline as of Jan 21 2017

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look on internet you can see Third Party Extensibility Packages are not support for Vs2008 or Vs2010 express editions by Microsoft.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsxprerelease/thread/c79aa771-01b3-47bd-a57f-a5e7f4d884ba

So, for you to be able to use wave-vs.net for Remote Pair Programming you will need Complete Visual Studio.Net Version (2008 or 2010)

Thank you for your interest.

wave-vs.net Development Team